# Pandas Dataframe performance vs list performance

Tags: python, pandas

I'm comparing two dataframes to determine if rows in df1 begin any row in df2. df1 is on the order of a thousand entries, df2 is in the millions.

This does the job but is rather slow.

```
df1['name'].map(lambda x: any(df2['name'].str.startswith(x)))
```

When run on a subset of df1 (10 items), this is the result:

```
35243     True
39980    False
40641    False
45974    False
53788    False
59895     True
61856    False
81083     True
83054     True
87717    False
Name: name, dtype: bool
Time: 57.8873581886 secs
```

When I converted df2 to a list, it runs much faster:

```
df2_list = df2['name'].tolist()

df1['name'].map(lambda x: any(item.startswith(x + ' ') for item in df2_list))

35243     True
39980    False
40641    False
45974    False
53788    False
59895     True
61856    False
81083     True
83054     True
87717    False
Name: name, dtype: bool
Time: 33.0746209621 secs
```

Why is it quicker to iterate through a list than a Series?

Comment: Iterating through pandas objects usually generates more overhead making them slower since they are much more complex then simpler built-in types like lists.

Comment: It might help you if you'd do something like `df2['name'].str.startswith(x).unique()` to boil down the size of the object that has to be search for every row in `df1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`any()` will early return when it get a `True` value, thus the `startswith()` calls is less then the `Dataframe` version.

Here is a method that use `searchsorted()`:

```
import random, string
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def randomword(length):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(length))


xs = pd.Series([randomword(3) for _ in range(1000)])
ys = pd.Series([randomword(10) for _ in range(10000)])

def is_any_prefix1(xs, ys):
    yo = ys.sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)
    y2 = yo[yo.searchsorted(xs)]
    return np.fromiter(map(str.startswith, y2, xs), dtype=bool)

def is_any_prefix2(xs, ys):
    x = xs.tolist()
    y = ys.tolist()
    return np.fromiter((any(yi.startswith(xi) for yi in y) for xi in x), dtype=bool)

res1 = is_any_prefix1(xs, ys)
res2 = is_any_prefix2(xs, ys)
print(np.all(res1 == res2))

%timeit is_any_prefix1(xs, ys)
%timeit is_any_prefix2(xs, ys)
```

output:

```
True
100 loops, best of 3: 17.8 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 2.35 s per loop
```

It's 100x faster.

Comment: Thank you for the insight on the any() function! 

There's something interesting going on with the scale of the dataset. When xs, xy are at the scales you've proposed, I find the same output you do. However, when I scale them up
xs = pd.Series([randomword(3) for _ in range(1000)])
ys = pd.Series([randomword(10) for _ in range(10000000)])

is_any_prefix2 runs faster. I probably need to dig into what's going on under the hood to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: I think maybe the `sort_values()` become slow when the series is large. you can split `ys` into chunks and run the algorithm only for failed `xs`.

Comment: Wow, splitting the series into chunks speeds it up significantly. Thank you for all of your help!